# WPF: How to detect rows rendering complete at DataGrid control?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to add a column to display sequence number without adding an extra property in the items source data and bind the sequence value in the binding property.

I added an event handler to the loading row event but I noticed that the last row's elements are not yet initialized during firing this event.

```
var dataGrid = new DataGrid();
dataGrid.LoadingRow += (s, e) =>
{
    if (dataGrid.ItemsSource != null && e.Row.GetIndex() + 1 == ((IList)dataGrid.ItemsSource).Count)
    {
        int participantColumnsCount = ((DataGridControlEntity)item).DisplayMembersPathEn.Count + 2;
        var elements = FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(dataGrid);
        int cellIdx = 0;
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= ((IList)dataGrid.ItemsSource).Count; idx++)
        {
            cellIdx = 0 + (idx * participantColumnsCount);
            if (cellIdx + 1 >= elements.Count())
                break;
            elements.ElementAt(cellIdx).Text = idx.ToString();
        }
    }
};
```

[image: Result after executing the above code snippet]
Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to find a fare workaround for this issue by subscribing to LayoutUpdated event rather than LoadingRow event.